# Earth Engine loop

Tags: google-earth-engine

This is a 2 part question...

I have a Feature Collection asset uploaded for which I want to extract the values of many different images at random points and write to a CSV file, where the name of the file is determined by an attribute in the table.  I have the points extraction running successfully, but only for a single feature at a time.  So my instinct is to stick the operation in a loop. Is this kind of loop the best approach here.  I have read the documentation and it indicates to map over the Feature Collection but it doesn't seem like the best approach here because I need the attribute for the CSV file name.

Second, in the loop below, with the variable len the loop won't run, however when I type in the known value 327, it completes.

```
var ftl = ee.List(table.aggregate_array('MLRARSYM'))
print(ftl)

var len = ftl.length()

for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
  var m = ftl.get(i)
  print(m)
}
```

Comment: That has to do with client-side, server-side objects. Read about that in the GEE documentation. if you apply var len = ftl.length().getInfo() it should work. However, mapping over the list is indeed preferred as it will calculate every index of the list at once. Add the part of code where you actually calculate what you want and it can be rewritten into a mapped function.

Comment: Thanks Kuik, adding getInfo() did the trick.  When mapping over a list, is it possible to expose the current item to get its value?